# Stub a method that does a callback using Sinon

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, sinon, chai

I would like to know if my approach is correct, and what is the best practice for similar situation.

**Scenario**

I am trying to use Sinon.js to stub a function call in my authController, which takes two arguments and process the result in a Callback function to pass it to Next() callback. something similar to this:

```
  // requestController.js
  module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
     authController.handle(req, res, function(apiMethod) {

        if (apiMethod !== undefined || apiMethod !== null) {
             apiMethod(next);
        } else {
             next();
        }
     });
 };
```

the above method is being called inside my requestController which handles all the requests and needed authController to check the authentication.

**The question** is how can I use sinon to stub or mock the behavior of `authController` and return a fake `apiMethod` but the rest of code continues and calls the `next()`.

Thanks in advance for your recommendations.

Comment: First off, your solution seems fine. To tell more, please post the code of your requestController. Are you using plain node.js or any framework?

Comment: @Sonata actually the first part is the logic inside requestController , and I am using express as web engine and mocha. just this. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: I have edited my question @Sonata.

Comment: Is your question answered?

Comment: @AlexanderElgin I found a workaround for it , but no not answered yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is still an error. For unit tests your code should look like this:

```
 module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
     apiMethod = function() {
        //your code goes here
     }

     authController.handle(req, res, apiMethod);
 };
```

The function wrapped around `apiMethod` is redundant